# How to deal with many templates in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating, knockout-3.0

While working with knockout I use [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) a lot. Because I am working on a single page application, my the amount of templates I am using is becoming bigger and bigger.

My main html started to look like this:

```
<!-- id's for knockout binding -->
<span id='...'>...</span>
<span id='...'>...</span>
....
<span id='...'>...</span>

<!-- templates -->
<script type="text/html" id="template_1">...</script>
<script type="text/html" id="template_2">...</script>
...
<script type="text/html" id="template_100">...</script>
```

Nonetheless everything works as expected, I am intimidated by the huge amount of templates, being loaded in the beginning.

So is there any best-practice regarding this issue, or how do people with good experience with knockout are dealing with it?

Answer (score 0):

External templates are better instead of having all templates in one file.by having external templates you can call them on demand rather loading all at a time.So there are many options available for external templates. for more information check out this [External Templates](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/31/using-external-templates-knockout-js/)